# Any unbounded function on a closed interval is discontinuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is this true? I think that it should be, considering $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is discontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$  whereas $g(x)=x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Would the answer change if we switched closed to an open interval $I$ such that $\vert I\vert<+\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true: One way to see this is to prove that the continuous image of a compact set is compact, and in particular bounded. Every closed, bounded interval is compact.

If the interval is open, then the choosing $f(x) = \frac 1 x$ on $(0, 1)$ gives an unbounded continuous function.

Comment: I see. So is the statement $f$ is continuous if and only if the the continuous image of a compact set is compact and bounded true? I only found the if statement in the textbook I am using

Comment: @user97554 I don't understand your comment: The second statement (cont. image of a compact set is compact) has nothing to do with $f$.

Comment: From what I understand, if $f$ is continuous on $T$ and $S\subset T$ is a compact set, the image of $S$, $f(S)$ is compact

Comment: @user97554 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: What I am wondering is whether if $f:T\rightarrow U$ and if $S\subset T: S\;is\;compact$ and if $f(S)\subset U:f(S)\;is\; compact$, does this imply that $f$ is continuous on $S$?

Comment: @user97554 No. Choose $f = \chi_{\Bbb Q}$, which is $1$ on the rationals and zero otherwise. Then the image of every compact set is either $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$ or $\{0, 1\$, which is always compact. But $f$ is gloriously discontinuous.